# Visual Studio 19-17 libraries compatibility according to GL flag

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have a pretty large C++ solution in VS2010 and I am going to upgrade it either to VS2017 or to VS2019 (2019 is more preferable) (It's fully clear that I have to rebuild all the third parties etc.) Also, I have a C++ solution on VS2017 which is not going to be updated to VS2019, and there is a chance that I'll include dynamic libraries (which means .h + .lib + .dll) from this sln to the main sln.
Some part of projects in both solutions uses /GL flag, so I am afraid: won't there be problems?
For example:

1. VS2019 with /GL refers to VS2017 .dll + .h + .lib built without /GL
2. VS2019 without /GL refers to VS2017 .dll + .h + .lib built with /GL
3. VS2019 with /GL refers to VS2017 .dll + .h + .lib built with /GL

On the idea, it should work fine, but I am not 100% sure. Did anyone have such experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole program optimisation doesn't affect the ABI of dlls.
"Program" refers to dlls or executables here. No optimisations are performed across dll boundaries.

You should make sure that any static libraries are all built with the same flag otherwise whole program optimisation won't work, the compiler prints a warning in this case.